# Kernel headers in LXC

Tags: makefile, driver, virtualization, lxc

I'm trying to compile some drivers in an LXC debian container (host is Ubuntu), but when it reach some module to install got this error:

```
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

I know that LXC shares kernel with the host.
There is a way to install those kernel headers and compile the driver in the container?
Thanks